# (jade) html tag for "each" in i18next namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, i18next

i have a i18next namespace containing a various number of entries in an array

```
"entries" : [
    "first"  : "bla",
    "second" : "blo",
    "third"  : "blu"
]
```

how can i make **each** of those a p in jade in one line?
(just like `p(data-i18n="entries")`, just not all in **one** `p`, but instead a `p`for each of the entries

i was thinking about something like

```
each entry in entries
    p(data-i18n="entry")
```

but i can't access the i18n content in jade like this (or can i?)

is there a way to do this?
other than

```
p(data-i18n="entries.0")
p(data-i18n="entries.1")
p(data-i18n="entries.2")
// and so on
```

### edit

real code:

```
p(data-i18n="[html]markup.userpageIntro")
// works, but puts everything in one p

each entry in markup.userpageIntro
  p(data-i18n=entry)
// doesn't work:
// Cannot read property 'userpageIntro' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You should require your JSON file like that:

```
var markup = require("markup-file.json");
```

and then pass it to your Jade file like that:

```
res.render('userpage', { user: req.user, markup: markup});
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'userpageIntro' of undefined   (the real name is markup.userpageIntro ), see my edit please

Comment: it seems like it, yes. at least in "jade-world". it is obviously defined in "i18n-world". how can i link those two?

Comment: sorry what do you mean exactly? it's served by node normally

Comment: uhmmmm res.render('userpage', {
              user: req.user,
            }); ?

Comment: but this IS the real problem. i don't have the markup available on my server as variable. it's just a namespace in a JSON containing my i18next-translations. it's not a normal variable

Comment: @user3787706 So include it in your JavaScript using `require()`: `var markup = require("markup-file.json");`

Comment: this could work :) but it's very much overhead. if it is loaded anyway, can i not ... just take it from there? i mean.. `p(data-i18n="[html]markup.userpageIntro.0")` does work. why can't i just loop through that somehow?